# How to test speed a query without result in MySQL

Tags: mysql, performance, load-time

I have queries that return thousands of results, is it posible to show only query time without actual results in MySQL console or from command line?

Comment: is this enough on cmd: `date && mysql < your_script.sql && date` ?

Comment: dont forget to redirect output to /dev/null

Comment: Is it posible to display time in seconds not datetimes? (the same as after the query in mysql console but without results).

Comment: To display time in seconds for a process, under Unix at least, use the `time` command: `/usr/bin/time -f "%e" -- mysql < your_script.sql > /dev/null`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `SET profiling = 1;` at command prompt.

[Refer for more details](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-profiles.html)

It's not possible to get the execution time without getting result or getting sql executed.

[See why we can not get execution time without actual query execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10702447/calculating-the-execution-time-of-a-mysql-query-based-on-the-number-of-records)

Answer (score 5):

If you're using Linux.

1. Create a file *query.sql*
2. Enter the query to test into it. e.g. `select * from table1`
3. Run this command:

`time mysql your_db_name -u'db_user_name' -p'your_password' < query.sql > /dev/null`

The output will look something like this:

```
real    0m4.383s    
user    0m0.022s    
sys     0m0.004s
```

the "real" line is what you're looking at. In the above example, the query took 4.38 seconds.

Obviously, entering your DB password on the command line is not such a great idea, but will do as a quick and dirty workaround.